# Delphi thread return value

Tags: multithreading, delphi, return-value

Can someone explain to me how I get a return value from myThread calling function test?

```
function test(value: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := value+2;    
end;

procedure myThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  test(Self.fParameters);
end;

procedure getvaluefromthread();
var
  Capture : myThread;
begin
  list := TStringList.Create;
  Capture := myThread.Create(False);
  Capture.fParameters := 2;
  Capture.Resume;
end;
```

Comment: Resume / Start should be avoided, it is not necessary to create the thread suspended. The actual Start of a non-create-suspended thread is done in AfterConstruction, which is called after all constructors have been called.

Comment: There is a `:=` missing in `test()`, not to mention the missing `begin`.

Comment: If you're really new to Delphi, maybe threads aren't where you should start learning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Declare a class derived from `TThread`.
2. Add a field, or multiple fields, to contain the result value or values.
3. Set the result value field(s) in the overridden `Execute` method.
4. When the thread has finished, read the result from the thread instance.

As Remy points out, if you wish to return just a single `Integer` value, then you can use the `ReturnValue` property of `TThread`. Use this in just the same way as described above. Note that the value placed in `ReturnValue` is the value returned by the underlying OS thread.

You can listen for `OnTerminate` to find out when thread is done. Or call `WaitFor`.

Note that you set the thread's parameters after it starts running. Either create the thread suspended, or pass the parameters to the constructor. Also, you should use `Start` rather than `Resume`. The latter is deprecated.

Comment: TThread has a [ReturnValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Classes.TThread.ReturnValue) property.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can of course use that. That's the value that will be returned by the underlying OS thread. Fine for 32 bit integers. If you want more, then you need to build that up.

Comment: `TThread.ReturnValue` does not return the underlying OS thread's result code, but it can be used to assign the result code. The user can assign whatever they want to `ReturnValue` inside of `Execute()` and it will be returned to the OS after `Execute()` exits. But `ReturnValue` is a property of `TThread`, so it can be read in the `OnTerminate` event, and is also used as the return value for `TThread.WaitFor()`.

Comment: @Remy You confirmed what I said. Simply that the value in ReturnValue is used as the underlying OS thread return value. I don't see why you are disagreeing with that. I wasn't contradicting you, just adding some more info.

Comment: I was not disagreeing with you, just your wording. You made it sound like `ReturnValue` receives the thread's result code from the OS, and that is not the case. It sets the result code that is returned back to the OS instead. That is all. Same idea, different semantics.

Comment: Could we call thread.Free in OnTerminate after reading the result?

Comment: @forsajt no because the object is still executing a method